# Find functions $F(\mathbf{x})$ invariant under a map $\mathbf{x} \to \mathbf{x'}$

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, reference-request, transformation

We introduce a map $\mathbf{x} \to \mathbf{x'}$, defined as (for example on $\mathbb{R}^3$):

$$x'=f(x,y,z) \\ y'=g(x,y,z) \\ z'=h(x,y,z)$$

Note that $f,g,h$ are not all linear (or at least, I'm not interested in the all linear case).

Imagine there is a function (family of functions) such that $F(\mathbf{x})=F(\mathbf{x'})$, or in our case:

$$F(x',y',z')=F(x,y,z)$$

For any $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ (or any other interval) and $x',y',z'$ determined by the transformation on $x,y,z.$

> How to find out if such a function exists or not for certain $f,g,h$?
>
> Is there a systematic way of searching for this function for arbitrary $f,g,h$? Or for some special cases?

A relaxed condition is also possible ($\alpha$ is a constant):

$$F(x',y',z')=\alpha F(x,y,z)$$

As an interesting example we can point out [Carlson's integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlson_symmetric_form):

$$F(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{\sqrt{(t+x)(t+y)(t+z)}}$$

$$F(x,y,z)=F \left( \frac{x+\lambda}{4}, \frac{y+\lambda}{4}, \frac{z+\lambda}{4} \right)$$

$$\lambda=\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{yz}+\sqrt{zx}$$

---

**Edit**

Title changed due to Christian Blatter's comment

Comment: When you say "For any $x,y,z,x',y',z' \in \mathbb{R}$." I suppose you mean "For any $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x',y',z'$ given by the transformation of $x,y,z$".

Comment: It sounds to me like you mean any function that is a function of the [b]points[/b] and not a function of the particular coordinate representation of that points.  Any function of a vector or tensor will do.

Comment: You don't have a "coordinate transformation" but a **map** $\phi:\>{\mathbb R}^3\to {\mathbb R}^3$ (maybe only defined on a subset $\Omega\subset{\mathbb R}^3$). This map moves points ${\bf x}\in\Omega$ to new positions ${\bf x}':=\phi({\bf x})\in\Omega$. You now are interested in functions $F:\>\Omega\to{\mathbb R}$ *invariant* under $\phi$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter, does it sound right now?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very general question! Here is an example of the kind of statements you have in mind: If
$$\phi:=(f,g,h):\quad\Omega\to{\mathbb R}^3,\qquad {\bf x}\mapsto{\bf x'}:=\phi({\bf x})$$
has a fixed point ${\bf p}\in\Omega$, and $\|d\phi({\bf p})\|<1$, then the point ${\bf p}$ is an *attracting* fixed point. In such a case there is a *basin of attraction* $\Omega'\subset\Omega$ such that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\phi^{\circ n}({\bf x})={\bf p}$$
for all ${\bf x}\in\Omega'$. It follows that for a continuous $\phi$-invariant $F$ one has  $F({\bf x})\equiv F({\bf p})$ on $\Omega'$.

Comment: Yes, exactly. And I understand that it's general - I want the reference on the methods of finding such functions. I added a reference-request tag